# Create set of sets using map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, set

I have declared a structure like:

```
struct data{
   vector<string> att;
};
```

And  `vector<data> v;`
is also created where each data having multiple att values.

Now based on the values in   `vector<string> att` for different objects I want to partition that `vector<data>` into multiple sets each set having all equal values in `vector<string> att;`

```
Ex- data set initially {1,2,3,4,5,6};



data  att[0] att[1] att[2] att[3]   

 1    it    should  be    clear  
 2    now   guess   it     is  
 3    xyz   ab      s       dd
 4    r     u       ok      now
 5    now   guess   it     is
 6    xyz   ab      s       dd  

after the partition procedure it becomes like:  

{{1}{2,5}{3,6}{4}}      // 1,2,... means the 1st,2nd data in vector<data>
```

How to do it using stl ?

**NOTE:**  integer is only to signify the order of data item in `vector<data>`

where I have to compare each element of `vector<string> att` for every two data item.

Comment: This question is profoundly unclear. Your pseudo-code-as-example contains integers, but `att` is a collection of strings. Can you clean up the presentation please?

Comment: @Kerrek SB I have edited.

Comment: You've just tacked on more words. That's like cleaning up the kitchen by sprinkling popcorn all over the floor. "Cleaning" means to re-examine the purpose of the question and presenting it in a systematic, orderly fashion.

Comment: @ Kerrek SB Is it still unclear? just have a look again in the example section

Comment: for sure map<vector<string>, vector<int> > makes no sense, what would it mean to have a vector of strings as the key of a map?

Comment: Since vectors are equality and order comparable, you could rephrase the question with `att` being a simple `int` and get the same answer in principle.

Comment: You basically want to sort something and keep track of the permutation. That must have been asked a thousand times already.

Comment: @ Kerrek SB But how is it possible that 'att' declared as int and strings are assigned to it and compared ?

Comment: @ pm100  can you please provide me a way to do it efficiently?

Comment: I just found this question, and I'm profoundly confused.  I don't see how you get your output from those inputs (or what it means).

Comment: @ Will Briggs From those input I just constructed a map like  map<vector<string>,vector<int> >     after this just by traversing it (iterator) find the output partions.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I mean that you can ask a much simpler question about `struct data { int att; }; std::vector<data>;` that gives you the same key insight into how to track the permutation created by sorting a collection. The vector-of-strings is a complete red herring.

Comment: @ Kerrek SB Ok but I have nothing to do with string or int , all that I want is to compare the values of att for each element in data vector and create a partition of the whole vector , where in each partition values of att are same.